# Not set Value for RadioButton in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use asp.net mvc with ViewEngine Razor and write the Radiobuttons so in html of the page:

```
<form id="ProductForm" method="post" action="@Url.Action("..", "..", new { area = "..." })">
<fieldset>
<div style="float: left; width: 550px; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <label for="DescriptionId">FullDescription</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <div style=" border: 1px solid Gray;">
                            <input type="hidden" name="DescriptionId" id="DescriptionId"/>
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" name="radioDescription" id="radioDescriptionNew" value="New" checked="checked" />New
                                <input type="radio" name="radioDescription" id="radioDescriptionExist" value="Exist" />Exist
                                <span id="DescriptionChooseHref" style=" visibility: hidden;">(<a href="#">Select</a>)</span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <textarea id="DescriptionText" style=" width: 530px; height: 200px; margin: 5px 0 5px 5px" placeholder="Full Description"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
...
</fieldset>
</form>
```

But when I run my site I see there in HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioDescription" value checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="radioDescription" value />
```

What I do wrong? Thank's.

Comment: your code works, i took a screen shot, see here: http://imgur.com/DboBk (in IE)

Comment: But it's so just in IE. In Chrome, Firefox and Opera I have the same problem.

Comment: put your code on jsfiddle.net (i also checked in all browsers and it still works)

Comment: can you show us any code surrounding this snipet?

Comment: Yes, I've edited text of answer.

Comment: I can also confirm that your code as you have posted is working with the full form showing even in IE8 :) Does the label render properly for you? could you be rendering a different version of the file? how are you calling this view?

Comment: You asked me and I've understood probably. It's strongly typed View. And Model have no properties for this labels:). I do its myself. Next question:). What may I do in this case?